# Gettting Google webfont as ttf with as much unicode characters as available?

Tags: css, unicode, truetype, google-font-api, woff2

When downloading the css resource for a Google webfont, the result seems to be dependent on the browser.

When I open this URL with my browser (Firefox or Chrome):

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto
```

I get [this result](https://pastebin.com/raw/fBFUwMja) which contains several woff2 font sources for different unicode character ranges.

When downloading the same CSS resouce URL with CURL for example, I get [this result](https://pastebin.com/raw/0n6kqca5) containing just one .ttf font, which appears to contain only a default unicode character range.

So apparently Google looks at the agent string from the HTTP request and then adjusts the result accordingly.

Is there a way to get a .ttf with the full unicode character range, i.e. everything that is also included with the "multi woff2" version? Most importantly the Latin and Latin-Extended characters.

I can convert woff2 fonts to ttf. However I don't know how to combine or merge multiple woff2 fonts into one ttf, or into one woff2 and then convert that.

Or am I doing something wrong and should I use a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1):

If you pick the font on the Google Fonts site, it'll show a dialog with the CSS code to use as webfont. Google will indeed send a specific version to your visitor's browser, depending on what it supports.

If you want the "full" fonts, grab the desktop version as .ttf file by clicking the download button. It'll have all the OpenType features and un-subsetted character set support.

[image]

Comment: @RocketNuts: this should be the accepted answer. Merging multiple woff2 to one big ttf might be possible but it's rather an overcomplicated approach. Downloading the ttf directly from google is certainly the easiest way to get the most complete glyph/character range.